# c# network client that is sending and receiving data from the same port on TCP

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, tcp

i've been tasked with writing a multi-threaded client (has a thread for sending data and a different thread for receiving data). for some reason the client (the one who pays for my job) insists that I use the same port for both sending (to the server) and receiving data (from the server). from what I remember this shouldn't be possible so that's why I'm here, to see if I was wrong.

sending thread:

```
public void Send_msg()
{
    while (!GlobalVar.is_conn) { }
    try
    {
        socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, GlobalVar._isTcp ? SocketType.Stream : SocketType.Dgram, GlobalVar._isTcp ? ProtocolType.Tcp : ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPEndPoint end_point = new IPEndPoint(Mul_ip, Mul_port);
        
        if (GlobalVar._isTcp)
        {
            socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseUnicastPort, true);
            socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
            socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Linger, true);
        }
        else
        {
            socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(Mul_ip, IPAddress.Any));
        }
        socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,Mul_port));
        socket.Connect(end_point);
        GlobalVar.socketWasConfiged = true;
        while (!_shouldStop)
        {
            while (!Send_msg_queue.IsEmpty)
            { //while there are more messages to send
                Send_msg_queue.TryDequeue(out CM_msg send_msg);
                byte[] send_buff = Encoder(send_msg);
                try
                {
                    socket.Send(send_buff, SocketFlags.None);
                    GlobalVar.Is_Wd_Rec = false;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error while trying to send a message: " + e.Message, "Error");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error while trying to send a message: " + e.Message, "Error");
    }
    finally
    {
        socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.DontLinger, true);
        socket.Close();
    }
```

as can be seen I open a socket, change its options via the setSocketOption, then I bind and connect to the server, afterwards the thread samples some queue and sends messages when there are so be sent.
simultaneously the thread that is supposed to be receiving messages does this:

```
        public void Receive_msg()
    {
        while (!GlobalVar.is_conn) { }
        try
        {
            while (!GlobalVar.socketWasConfiged) { }
            byte[] rec_buff = new byte[size];
            socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,GlobalVar._isTcp? SocketType.Stream : SocketType.Dgram,GlobalVar._isTcp? ProtocolType.Tcp : ProtocolType.Udp);
            IPEndPoint end_point = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Mul_port);
            if(GlobalVar._isTcp)
            {
                socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseUnicastPort, true);
                socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
                socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 1);
                socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Linger, true);
            }
            else
            {
                socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(Mul_ip, IPAddress.Any));
            }

            socket.Bind(end_point);
            socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(Mul_ip, Mul_port));

            while (!_shouldStop)
            {
                size_rec = socket.Receive(rec_buff);
                GlobalVar.Counter_auto = GlobalVar.Counter_auto + 1;
                Receive_msg_queue.Enqueue(Decoder(rec_buff));
                // if a message was recieved than there is a connection to the unit, so we make Is_Wd_Rec true
                GlobalVar.Is_Wd_Rec = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occur while trying to receive a message: " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.DontLinger, true);
            socket.Close();
        }
    }
```

as can be seen, the listener thread waits till some globalVar is true (so we don't get concurrent socket binds), and then it initializes the socket and tries to bind/connect to the server. once it tries to connect I get an exception that it cannot connect to a socket that is already connected.

is there any way to work around this? or should I be telling the client that the server should write to a different port?

Comment: Clients usually use ephemeral ports at the client end. This is normal and expected. Can it use a static port as a client? ...maybe? But: unusual

Comment: the server has only 1 client (the one im writing), so I guess we don't need temporary ports in that situation

Comment: Have the two threads use the same socket. One thread reads from the socket, the other thread writes to the socket.  The requirement to set a source port is flawed. There is no reason to do this. Someone needs some education on how tcp/ip works.

Comment: @amirsarusi use of ephemeral ports has nothing to do with the number of clients connecting to the server. In this situation, I'm guessing your employer has locked down their network, that is probably why they are insisting on the client socket use a specific port to connect from. Simply call `Socket.Bind()` to set that local port before calling `Socket.Connect()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you, i will try and open the socket from the main application before sending a reference to both reader and writer. in my main i will also bind and connect the socket before using it.